# Returning all maximum or minimum values that can be multiple

Tags: ruby, max, min, maxby

`Enumerable#max_by` and `Enumerable#min_by` return **one** of the relevant elements (presumably the first one) when there are multiple max/min elements in the receiver. For example, the following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5].max_by{|e| e % 3}
```

returns only `2` (or only `5`).

Instead, I want to return **all** max/min elements and in an array. In the example above, it would be `[2, 5]` (or `[5, 2]`). What is the best way to get this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 5]

arr.group_by{|a| a % 3} # => {1=>[1], 2=>[2, 5], 0=>[3]}
arr.group_by{|a| a % 3}.max.last # => [2, 5]
```

Comment: Your use of `group_by` is nice, but I think you can improve a step further by replacing `sort` with `max_by` on the keys.

Comment: Or just `arr.group_by{|a| a % 3}.max.last`

Comment: @steenslag That is shorter, but from efficiency, isn't it better to use Schwarzian transform? (I may be wrong. Not sure how it works without a block)

Comment: @sawa you're right. fruity: max_by is faster than max by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%  
max is faster than sort by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%

Comment: I ended up doing `arr.group_by{|a| a % 3}.max_by(&:first).last`, which is the fastest, and is reasonably simple. Thanks to Sergio and steenslag.

Comment: @sawa: I realized just now that *you* are the OP :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you do not mind then may I ask you what does OP stand for? -- Thanks

Comment: @AlokAnand: original poster

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
mods=arr.map{|e| e%3}
```

> ## find max

```
max=mods.max
indices = []
mods.each.with_index{|m, i| indices << i if m.eql?(max)}
arr.select.with_index{|a,i| indices.include?(i)}
```

> ## find min

```
min = mods.min
indices = []
mods.each.with_index{|m, i| indices << i if m.eql?(min)}
arr.select.with_index{|a,i| indices.include?(i)}
```

Sorry for clumsy code, will try to make it short.

Answer by @Sergio Tulentsev is the best and efficient answer, found things to learn there. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is the hash equivalent of @Serio's use of `group_by`.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 5]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |e,h| h[e%3] << e }.max.last
  #=> [2, 5]
```

The steps:

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |e,h| h[e%3] << e }
  #=> {1=>[1], 2=>[2, 5], 0=>[3]}
a = h.max
  #=> [2, [2, 5]]
a.last
  #=> [2, 5]
```