# Index of multiple array maxima

Tags: ruby, indexing, max

To get the index of the maximum of an array `arr = [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,3]`, I can do:

```
arr.each_with_index.max
```

and get `[3, 7]`. However, I don't want to miss the `[3, 3]` and `[3, 6]`. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115956/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.each_with_index.group_by(&:first).max.last
# => [[3, 3], [3, 6], [3, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mx = arr.max
[mx, arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i] == mx }]
  #=> [3, [3, 6, 7]]
```