# How to use &proc argument inside method

Tags: ruby

`Array#max_by` returns only a single value, but I want to have all values that have the max value.

```
hashes = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:2, b:3}, {a:1, b:3}]
max = hashes.map{|h| h[:b]}.max
hashes.select{|h| h[:b] == max}
# => [{a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 1, b: 3}]
```

This code works fine, and I want to add it to `Array` class.

```
class Array
  def max_values_by(&proc)
    max = map(&proc).max
    # I don't know how to use `select` here.
  end
end
```

How to access the value of the `&proc` argument?

Comment: A more straightforward way to solve your problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115956.

Comment: BTW, `&block` is a more common name for this variable.

Comment: I agree with @Stefan.  Using the name `proc` is misleading because one might expect it to contain a lambda or non-lambda Proc instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `proc` in the block passed to `select` by calling it with `call`:

```
class Array
  def max_values_by(&proc)
    max = map(&proc).max
    select { |h| proc.call(h) == max }
  end
end
hashes.max_values_by { |h| h[:b] }
=> [{a: 2, b: 3}, {a: 1, b: 3}]
```

or with `yield`, which gives identical results:

```
def max_values_by(&proc)
  max = map(&proc).max
  select { |h| yield(h) == max }
end
```

Although `proc.call` is a little longer than `yield`, I prefer it in this case because it makes it clearer that the same block is being used in two places in the method, and because it's weird to use both the implicit block passing of `yield` and the explicit passing of `&proc` in the same method.

Comment: You can also use `yield(h)` instead of `proc.call(h)`

Comment: Added, thanks. There is `Proc#yield` too, but that's just confusing.

Comment: You think `Proc#yield`'s confusing? You can also call the proc with  `(proc === h)` (and with `[]`, as mentioned by the OP, and by the depricated-but-still-with-us `proc.(h)`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I didn't know that `.()` is deprecated.  I googled but could not find anything about it.  Could you point me to where I could find out more about it?

Comment: @Keith, maybe I was wrong about that. I thought I had read that but can't find a reference. `Proc#()` is not listed as a [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) instance method in v2.2.0, but that doc also states, "prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide 'call'".

Answer (score 1):

@DaveSchweisguth suggests a great implementation using `select`, like you requested. Another way of achieving the same result is by using `group_by`, like this:

```
>> hashes.group_by{|h| h[:b]}.max.last
=> [{:a=>2, :b=>3}, {:a=>1, :b=>3}]
```

or monkey-patched into Array as:

```
class Array
  def max_values_by(&proc)
    group_by(&proc).max.last
  end
end
```

Comment: That is not what the OP asked. But is the same as the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115956.