# Return min values of hash with duplicate values

Tags: ruby

For example, if I have the hash `{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 1}`, I want `["a", "c"]`.

I can do `hash.min_by{|k,v| v}`, but that only returns the first match (`"a"=>1`).

How do I get it to recognize duplicates and return `{"a"=> 1, "c"=> 1}`?

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115956

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 1}.group_by(&:last).min.last.map(&:first)
# => ["a", "c"]
```

or

```
{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 1}.group_by(&:last).min.last.to_h.keys
# => ["a", "c"]
```

Comment: ...or `h.group_by(&:last).min.last.to_h #=> {"a"=>1, "c"=>1}` to provide the result in the form requested. Readers: note that `min` applies to key-value pairs (two-element arrays) of the hash produced by `group_by`.

Answer (score 7):

That operation is a bit unusual for a hash, so it’s not very neat:

```
min_value = hash.values.min
min_pairs = hash.select { |k, v| v == min_value }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write FORTRAN in any language! :)

It has the advantage of only requiring 1 pass :

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 1}

min = Float::INFINITY
values_for_min = []

hash.each do |key, value|
  case value <=> min
  when 0
    values_for_min << key
  when -1
    min = value
    values_for_min = [key]
  end
end

p min
#=> 1
p values_for_min
#=> ["a", "c"]
```